# doctrine not removing entity assertion constraints

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-forms

I used to have a entity assertion

```
#[ORM\Column(
        type: 'string',
        name: 'password',
        length: 20,
        nullable: false
    )]
#[Assert\NotBlank]
    #[Assert\Length(
        max: 20
        nullable: true
    )]
    private string $password
```

but I removed it then

```
#[ORM\Column(
        type: 'string',
        name: 'password',
        length: 20,
        nullable: true
    )]
private ?string $password;
```

I am facing the form error 'this value should not be blank error' when I fill up the form and this error only happens in production environment.

things I have performed:

- removed the field from form
- removed from twig where form was render
- run migration which set field `abc` default null
- tried clearing doctrine metadata cache

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the previous entity assertion constraints are still cached in Doctrine's metadata cache. You could try clearing the Doctrine metadata cache again, making sure that you clear both the production and dev environments, as they may have separate caches.

If clearing the cache doesn't work, you could also try clearing the Symfony cache using the command `php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod` to make sure that any cached data is cleared from the production environment.

Additionally, you might want to check if there are any other places in your code where the old assertion constraints may be still being used or referenced, such as in a validation group or in a custom validation constraint.

If none of these steps work, you may want to check your database schema and make sure that it matches your updated entity class, as it's possible that there are still constraints set on the database level. You could also try running `php bin/console doctrine:schema:validate` to validate your schema against your entity class and ensure that they are in sync.